# Small issue with the Domain Name System (DNS) Server Cmdlets

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, windows-server-2012, dns-server

I'm wondering if I need to clear some cache or something with the issue I'm having.

I'm trying to remove A records from a DNS Zone and replacing them with a CName record that has the same host name.

```
Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -Zonename $line -InputObject $record -Force
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Zonename $line -Name $hostname -TimeToLive $ttl -HostNameAlias $target
```

This throws me:

> Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName : Failed to create resource record @ in zone zone.tld on server NS01.
>   At C:\admin\updatettl.ps1:56 char:4
>   +             Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Zonename $line -Name $hostname > -TimeToLive  ...
>   +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (@:root/Microsoft/...urceRecordCName) > [Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName]
>      , CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 9709,Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsofts DNS Server implementation will not allow you to create a CNAME at the zone apex as per [RFC 1034 §3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034.html#section-3.6.2).

The error you receive (9709, [`DNS_ERROR_CNAME_COLLISION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391(v=vs.85).aspx#dns_error_cname_collision)) is a bit cryptic, but you won't (and shouldn't) be able to add it anyways.

On the other hand, placing a CNAME RR at the apex effectively introduces a collision with the NS and SOA records for the zone, at which point the error does make some sense

Comment: Seems that is correct.
When I try to create a CName on @ it throws me this error but when the hostname is set to something like "www" it has no problems with this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully create an ALIAS or CNAME using the following syntax as suggested in the Microsoft Documentation

```
PS C:> Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Name "THE-NEW-ALIAS-NAME" -HostNameAlias "ALREADY-EXISTING-NAME" -ZoneName "example.com"
```

Example-Test:

```
PS C:> Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Name "mylabcn" -HostNameAlias "cslab" -ZoneName "example.com"
```

mylabcn: The new ALIAS to be created to the existing name:cslab.example.com

Here the `-Name` parameter is the new ALIAS/CNAME to be created and the `-HostNameAlias` paramater is the already existing-name to which the new ALIAS name would be created.

Initially I used the above parameters in opposite way, which resulted in the exact above error "9709"

Hope this helps.